# Onion smell getting on fruits

Tags: fruit, cutting-boards

I use a recently-purchased bamboo large-and-heavy cutting board to cut/chop/dice/slice veggies and fruit.  However, my routine is such that I typically dice a red onion at night, and a green apple for breakfast.

I've noticed that the red onion smell and, to some extent, taste gets on my green apple in the morning.

I read online about people treating their cutting board with coconut oil or something before using it. I failed to do that.  Is it too late to do it now?  Will it solve my problem?  Are there other ways to prevent the onion smell-and-taste to get on fruit?

Comment: Do you wash off your cutting board after cutting the onion?

Comment: I do, with soap.

Comment: a scrub with some baking soda might help cut the odors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My experience is that washing doesn't effectively get rid of onion or garlic odors from cutting boards.

Either get another - maybe lighter weight and cheaper - cutting board for fruits, or flip your current board over, and use the "bottom" side for delicately scented items, etc. Mark the "top" side with an "o" for "onion" (or some such discreet indicator) in permanent marker, so you will remember in future which is which.

Getting housemates to comply is a separate problem.

Comment: Great idea on marking the different sides and using one side for fruit and the other for veggies.  What type of marker should I use that (a) doesn't wash off, and (b) doesn't introduce cancerous/bad chemicals into my food?

Comment: Mark it in the very corner with a Permanent marker type felt pen, something like a "Sharpie" marker. Yes it has a strong solvent odor, and I don't imagine it would be healthful to, like, suck on one, but marking the cutting board is minimal ...  Or you could use a pencil. Pencil doesn't seem to wash off either, and they don't really have lead in them.

Comment: Alright, thanks @Lorel C.  I'll leave the question unanswered for another few hours to let other people answer, maybe they have different suggestions. Then I'll mark this as correct if no other suitable solutions have been suggested. Thanks again.

Comment: @LorelC. : you can also mark it along the edge -- a series of arrows or even just a line of 'V's so that you can differentiate between the two sides.